# Align button to right side in div

Tags: css, mudblazor

I have below markup

```
div class="d-flex flex-column">
<MudText Typo="Typo.h1" class="mb-2">Employees</MudText>
<MudItem  >
    <MudButton Variant="Variant.Outlined" Color="Color.Secondary" style ="float:right" >CreateNew</MudButton>
</MudItem>
<MudPaper class="d-flex flex-column h-100" style="min-height: 0;">
    <MyForm/>
    <div class="d-flex h-100" style="min-height: 0;">
        <MudTable Items="Items" FixedHeader="true" Height="100%" Style="width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 52px);"
                  MultiSelection="true" SelectOnRowClick="false">
            <HeaderContent>
                <MudTh>Length</MudTh>
                <MudTh>Age</MudTh>
            </HeaderContent>
            <RowTemplate>                   
                <MudTd DataLabel="StartIndex">2</MudTd>
                <MudTd DataLabel="Length">2</MudTd>
                <MudTd DataLabel="Edit">
                    <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Edit" aria-label="edit" ></MudIconButton>
                    <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Delete" aria-label="delete"></MudIconButton>
                </MudTd>
            </RowTemplate>
        </MudTable>

    </div>
</MudPaper>
```

I want CreateNew button to be on right side of text `Employees` and to the extreme right
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h1" class="mb-2">Employees</MudText>
    <MudItem  >
        <MudButton Variant="Variant.Outlined" Color="Color.Secondary">CreateNew</MudButton>
    </MudItem>
</div>
```

Comment: Then it moves grid also to the right

Comment: It moves mudtable also to top and to the right. its wrong

Comment: Can you show me an image after change this?

Comment: i cant attach image in comment

Comment: Make sure you only wrap MudText and MudItem with div have class "d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between" like I mention before. I still wonder how it can be affect to MudTable.

Comment: Yes i have done as you said

Comment: Ah ok you moved my mudtable out of div? where should it go?

Comment: No no, I mean you make another div to wrap only 2 element like I mention. Don't change anything of the parent div

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).